# How to calculate an expression in the third column based on the values of first 2 columns?

Tags: sql, expression

This is what CHATGPT is suggesting but I dont think thats right. Please help

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable (
    COLA INT,
    COLB INT,
    COLC_EXPRESSION NVARCHAR(MAX)
);

INSERT INTO YourTable (COLA, COLB, COLC_EXPRESSION)
VALUES (5, 10, 'COLA + 2*COLB');
```

-- Create a view with dynamic SQL to evaluate expressions

```
CREATE VIEW ComputedValues AS
SELECT 
    COLA,
    COLB,
    COLC_EXPRESSION AS Expression,
    CASE 
        WHEN COLC_EXPRESSION IS NOT NULL THEN 
            CAST(
                (
                    SELECT COLA + 2 * COLB -- Replace with your actual expression evaluation logic
                    FROM YourTable 
                    WHERE t.COLA = YourTable.COLA AND t.COLB = YourTable.COLB
                ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
            )
        ELSE 
            NULL 
    END AS COLC
FROM YourTable t;
```

Comment: Please tag the RDBMS you are using